# AKKA Shutdown Pattern doesn't work

Tags: akka

After I read this excellent blog written by the AKKA team, [Shutdown Patterns in AKKA 2](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2), I run the code and it indeed works.

But when I do another experiment with a slight change, throwing out an exception in workers, then this pattern won't work. Since it's reasonable that workers may throw any kinds of exceptions during working, right?

The following are my code, two files:

Reaper.scala, copied from the article mentioned above:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Terminated}
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Reaper {
  // Used by others to register an Actor for watching
  case class WatchMe(ref: ActorRef)
}

abstract class Reaper extends Actor {
  import Reaper._

  // Keep track of what we're watching
  val watched = ArrayBuffer.empty[ActorRef]

  // Derivations need to implement this method.  It's the
  // hook that's called when everything's dead
  def allSoulsReaped(): Unit

  // Watch and check for termination
  final def receive = {
    case WatchMe(ref) =>
      context.watch(ref)
      watched += ref
    case Terminated(ref) =>
      watched -= ref
      if (watched.isEmpty) allSoulsReaped()
  }
}
```

TestWorker.scala

```
import akka.actor.{SupervisorStrategy, Props, ActorSystem, Actor}
import Reaper._


class TestReaper extends Reaper {
  def allSoulsReaped(): Unit = context.system.shutdown()
  override val supervisorStrategy = SupervisorStrategy.stoppingStrategy
}

// The reaper sends this message to all workers to notify them to start work
case object StartWork

class TestWorker extends  Actor {
  def receive = {
    case StartWork =>
      // do real work ...
      throw new IllegalStateException("Simulate uncaught exceptions during work")
  }
}

object TestWorker {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("system")
    val reaper = system.actorOf(Props[TestReaper])
    val worker1 = system.actorOf(Props[TestWorker])
    val worker2 = system.actorOf(Props[TestWorker])

    reaper ! WatchMe(worker1)
    reaper ! WatchMe(worker2)
    Thread.sleep(3000) // make sure WatchMe will be delivered before StartWork
    worker1 ! StartWork
    worker2 ! StartWork
    system.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

This program will hang forever.

It seems the reaper cannot receive `Terminated` messages if workers throw uncaught exceptions

Can somebody tell my why? Many thanks in advance!

**Correct answer** by @mattinbits:

The reason that this program hangs forever is that in my code `TestWorker` are not children of `TestReaper` even `TestReaper` calls  `context.watch(ref)`.

**context.watch() doesn't mean becoming a child.** `context.watch(ref)` just means that `TestReaper` will get notified when a `TestWorker` actor dies.

`SupervisorStrategy` and `context.watch()` are two different things. `SupervisorStrategy` will only have influence on all children actors.

Putting  `override val supervisorStrategy = SupervisorStrategy.stoppingStrategy` in the `TestReaper` won't make `TestWorker` stopped when exceptions happen inside `TestWorker`.  Instead we need to change the `SupervisorStrategy` of  `TestWorker`s parent actor. Since all actors in the code above are created by `system.actorOf()`, they are children of the [Guardian Actor `/user`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html#_user__The_Guardian_Actor), so actually we need to change the supervision strategy of the `/user` actor , by adding `akka { actor { guardian-supervisor-strategy = "akka.actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy" } }` in `application.conf`

However, it's better to use another actor as the supervision actor, just like what @mattinbits does in his code.

Comment: Did you confirmed that the time `Reaper` recieved the `WatchMe` message is prior to the time that the workers recieved `StartWork` message? Since `!` is asynchronous, there will be a possibility that `StartWork`  comes before `WatchMe`

Comment: I added `Thread.sleep(3000)` between `reaper ! WatchMe(worker2)` and `worker1 ! SartWork`, still hang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not enough to watch the actors, you also have to make sure the actors stop (which is the condition under which `Terminated` gets sent).

By default, when an actor throws an exception, the strategy is to restart it. You need to give the actors a supervisor which will apply the `Stop` directive.

Have a look at the following, both tests pass (with Reaper unchanged from your version above):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
import Reaper.WatchMe
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Stop
import akka.actor._
import akka.testkit.{TestProbe, TestKit}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Matchers, WordSpecLike, WordSpec}
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case object StartWork

class TestReaper extends Reaper {
  def allSoulsReaped(): Unit = context.system.shutdown()
}

class TestWorker extends  Actor {
  def receive = {
    case StartWork =>
      // do real work ...
      throw new IllegalStateException("Simulate uncaught exceptions during work")
  }
}

class TestParent(reaper: ActorRef, probe: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Start" =>
      val worker1 = context.actorOf(Props[TestWorker])
      val worker2 = context.actorOf(Props[TestWorker])
      reaper ! WatchMe(worker1)
      reaper ! WatchMe(worker2)
      worker1 ! StartWork
      worker2 ! StartWork
  }

  override def supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case ex: IllegalStateException =>
      probe ! "Stopped a worker"
      Stop
  }
}


class TestSupervision extends TestKit(ActorSystem("Test"))
with WordSpecLike
with Matchers
with BeforeAndAfterAll{

  "Supervision" should {

    "Stop the actor system when the parent stops the workers" in {
      val reaper = system.actorOf(Props[TestReaper])
      val probe = TestProbe()
      val parent = system.actorOf(Props(new TestParent(reaper, probe.ref)))
      parent ! "Start"
      probe.expectMsg("Stopped a worker")
      probe.expectMsg("Stopped a worker")
      import system.dispatcher
      val terminatedF = Future {
        system.awaitTermination()
      }
      Await.ready(terminatedF, 2 seconds)
    }
  }

  override def afterAll(){
    system.shutdown()
  }
}

class TestLackSupervision extends TestKit(ActorSystem("Test2"))
with WordSpecLike
with Matchers
with BeforeAndAfterAll{

  "Lack of Supervision" should {
    "Not stop the actor system when the workers don't have an appropriate parent" in {
      val reaper = system.actorOf(Props[TestReaper])
      val worker1 = system.actorOf(Props[TestWorker])
      val worker2 = system.actorOf(Props[TestWorker])
      reaper ! WatchMe(worker1)
      reaper ! WatchMe(worker2)
      import system.dispatcher
      val terminatedF = Future { system.awaitTermination()}
      a [TimeoutException] should be thrownBy Await.ready(terminatedF, 2 seconds)
    }
  }

  override def afterAll(){
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

By default when actors throw an exception they are restarted. Since supervision strategy is applied from parent to child, the TestParent exists to enforce the `Stop` directive on the children. Your original code would not work for this reason.

If you want top level actors (Those launched with `system.actorOf`) to stop on an exception, you could set the configuration property `akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy = "akka.actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy"` but in my example I prefer to use a parent actor since actor hierarchies are a normal way to organise supervision in Akka.

To run as an app, do something similar to the following:

```
object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("Example")
  val reaper = system.actorOf(Props[TestReaper])
  val dummyProbe = system.actorOf(Props(new Actor{

    def receive = {
      case "Stopped a worker" => println("Stopped a worker")
    }

  }))
  val parent = system.actorOf(Props(new TestParent(reaper, dummyProbe)))
  parent ! "Start"
  system.awaitTermination()
}
```

To stop the exceptions from being printed on the command line and muddying the output, change the supervision strategy as follows:

```
override def supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(loggingEnabled = false) {...}
```

Comment: Good point, but actually by default `preRestart()` will stop the actor,  however, even I add a line `override val supervisorStrategy = SupervisorStrategy.stoppingStrategy` to the parent actor, the parent actor still will not receive `Terminated` messages and the program will still hang there.

Comment: preRestart calls postStop, but it doesn't sent the Terminated message. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Actor_Lifecycle

Comment: Have updated my answer with a working, tested example.

Comment: I tried your code, it works, also the code in AKKA teams blog also works in unite test, but after I take the code out and put it into a `main()` function, it just hangs there, the parent actor doesn't receive `Terminated` messages. Can you modify your code to have a `main()` entry function?

Comment: I've added an example of using this code in an App which works for me when run with `sbt 'run-main Main'`

Comment: Excellent! But I still have one question, why do you need a third actor named `TestParent `? In my code I only have one `TestReaper` actor and two `TestWorker` actors. I want to keep the code minimal and find out why my code doesn't work

Comment: @soulmachine I've added a couple of paragraphs to my answer on that subject. I believe your code doesn't work because there is no supervision strategy in play to prevent your workers being restarted when they throw.

Comment: You're correct, after putting  `akka {
  actor {
    guardian-supervisor-strategy = "akka.actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy"
  }
}` in `application.conf` the Reaper could finally receive `Terminated` message. Thank you very much!